# Changing orientation of all children of LinearLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout (child) inside another (parent) LinearLayout. I want to change the orientation of the parent from horizontal to vertical and vice versa and do the same for all children. How can i propagate this orientation change from parent to its children with adding any additional interface.

Btw, this has nothing to with orientation change of the device. I want the  orientation to change as per event encountered.

I can have multiple LinearLayout as its children and i don't want to set the orientation of all of these in a for loop since i am adding children programmatically

Comment: Well have you tried to set the orientation?

Comment: i can call the setOrienation for parent. but how to propagate this to its children. i can have multiple LinearLayout as its children and i dont want to set the orientation of all of these in a for loop since i am adding children programmatically

Comment: You can find the children of a layout programmatically. So i do not understand what it would matter if you added some by code.

Answer (score 2):

```
ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llayout);
ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llayout2);
```

Use `setOrientation` to change the orientation.

```
ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
yourLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Do the same for the children